# Banning PHP.net from the review queue

Tags: discussion, review-audits, disputed-review-audits, external-links, banning

So I have been banned from the review queue several times (I'm currently on the 1 month ban), always for "erring" on the side of niceness.

Most recently I was banned for saying an answer to a PHP question was "No Action Needed" when it referred to the needed PECL package on PHP.net (see https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/10641064). The audit failed because "Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes."

I am curious why **PHP.net** is considered a more ephemeral link than the jsfiddle, codepen and other links I see all the time among accepted questions and answers?

Would it really have been a better answer to name the required PHP extension without a link to where it can be obtained for installation??

Comment: Niceness should not be criteria used to judge the quality of posts on Stack Overflow. Posts don't care if you're nice or mean to them, they have no feelings.

Comment: *the jsfiddle, codepen and other links I see all the time* - If you are seeing questions/answers with these links and no code you should either be editing them to fix that or flagging & down voting. Posts should be useful and make sense even if the links in them fail. The comment on the answer is completely correct.

Comment: recommended reading: **[Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/165773)** "let me be clear: **this sort of response is *not* an answer**. If you see this, flag it. Moderators, if you see it flagged, *delete it*"

Comment: If you're going to "err" on any side, it should always be on the side of skipping. If you don't know, skip.

Answer (score 8):

> The audit failed because...

you said that a 'bad answer' was a 'good answer'. If you examine the question, you will see a very nice problem ("yiisoft/yii2-mongodb 2.0.4 requires ext-mongo >=1.5.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongo is missing from your system." which is a dependency issue) and the answer don't even address this problem. As always, if you don't have knowledge on what you are reviewing, skip is your friend.

Comment: So having the 1.6.12 mongo extension is not a valid solution for needing a mongo extension greater than 1.5.0? It was the link, not the substance being emphasized as wrong.

Comment: @wogsland **everything is wrong**. If you want someone to install something, you tell them *how*. The answer failed to do that at multiple levels, as don't even follow the procedure [to install the extension](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/mongodb.installation.php.php), but just offers a package listing. As it is, **it doesn't solve the problem** in essence nor in form.